# Boost Python's vector_indexing_suite seems to break the use of return_internal_reference. Am I missing something?

Tags: python, c++, boost

I can create a class Foo that returns an internal reference to a class Bar and everything seems to work just fine. However, when I try and expose a vector of Foo using the vector_indexing_suite, I get some weird behavior. That is, a reference to the underlying Bar of a Foo in a vector of Foos gets corrupted when a new Foo is appended to the vector.

Since most of the code comes straight out of the Boost Python docs, I assume it should work. In other words, I don't think that I am doing anything outrageous. However, I am also relatively new to Boost Python. Am I missing something here?

The issue can be replicated rather easily by modifying an [example](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/python/doc/html/reference/function_invocation_and_creation/models_of_callpolicies.html#function_invocation_and_creation.models_of_callpolicies.boost_python_return_internal_ref.example) from the Boost documentation resulting in the following code.

```
#include <boost/python/module.hpp>
#include <boost/python/class.hpp>
#include <boost/python/return_internal_reference.hpp>
#include <boost/python/suite/indexing/vector_indexing_suite.hpp>


#include <vector>

class Bar
{
 public:
   Bar(int x) : x(x) {}
   int get_x() const { return x; }
   void set_x(int x) { this->x = x; }

   bool operator==(const Bar &other) const { return other.x == x;}
   bool operator!=(const Bar &other) const { return !(other == (*this)); }

 private:
   int x;
};

class Foo
{
 public:
   Foo(int x) : b(x) {}

   // Returns an internal reference
   Bar const& get_bar() const { return b; }

   bool operator==(const Foo &other) const {return other.b == b;}
   bool operator!=(const Foo &other) const { return !(other == (*this)); }

 private:
   Bar b;
};

using namespace boost::python;
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(boosttest)
{
   class_<Bar>("Bar", init<int>())
      .def("get_x", &Bar::get_x)
      .def("set_x", &Bar::set_x)
      ;

   class_<Foo>("Foo", init<int>())
      .def("get_bar", &Foo::get_bar
          , return_internal_reference<>())
      ;

   class_<std::vector<Foo>>("FooList")
      .def(vector_indexing_suite<std::vector<Foo>>())
      ;
}
```

When using the resulting module in Python, a reference to the Bar of a Foo in a FooList ends up pointing to garbage when a new Foo is appended to the FooList as shown below.

```
>>> import boosttest
>>> foolist = boosttest.FooList()
>>> foolist.append(boosttest.Foo(2))
>>> foo_ref = foolist[0]
>>> bar_ref = foo_ref.get_bar()
>>> bar_ref.get_x()
2
>>> foolist.append(boosttest.Foo(3))
>>> bar_ref.get_x()
-572662307
>>> foo_ref.get_bar().get_x()
2
```

Note: In trying to figure out what is going on here, I set a breakpoint to trigger when the underlying value of x changes. From the resulting stack trace, it appears that the value is getting changed when std::vector's underlying array is getting swapped out to accommodate for the new value being appended. Testing the code verified that, sure enough, if several values are appended and then removed then memory corruption doesn't occur when appending to the Foo List. In other words, since the underlying array has already been resized, several values can be appended without causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In what I was trying to do, I was focused on the behavior I wanted in the Python interface but was failing to appreciate what was happening in the underlying C++ code.

Essentially, the situation I was creating in my Boost Python interface was a pointer to a data member of an element of a vector. When a new value was added to the vector the underlying array had to be reallocated causing any pointers or references to the data to be invalidated. This invalidation is explained [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/) and in many other C++ references, I'm sure.

Note that, from the Python side, any reference to an element (Foo) of the vector_indexing_suite object behaved as expected. It was only the reference to a member (Bar) of the element, which was obtained using Boost's return_internal_reference, that ran into issues. As [stated](https://github.com/boostorg/python/issues/299) by one of the maintainers of the Boost project, be very careful when using Boost's return_internal_reference funtionality.